# How can I access my vue instance when in a v-for loop?

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

I have a v-for loop

```
<div v-for="index in 6" :key="index">
      <div class="card h-100" style="margin-top: 200px;">
        <a href="#">
          <img
            class="card-img-top"
            src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/345/700/400.jpg?hmac=oQMF95pIPaAEnln8qWEjerYF_2lcuFsfl_KnwjHnpXc"
            alt
          />
        </a>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h4 class="card-title">
            <a href="#"><p>{{ this.itemData[index].name }}</p></a>
          </h4>
          <p
            class="card-text"
          >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet numquam aspernatur!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
          <small class="text-muted">&#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9734;</small>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'itemData' of undefined
```

However, I can reference this same line of code outside of the loop and it will be displayed.
I also get issues when I run this.itemData[0].price, price being a present element in the itemData[0] object. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'itemData' of undefined` happens because you're using `this.` prefix within the template, which is not recommended.

I've even found that there's a rule for that in the official ESLint plugin for vue:
https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/this-in-template.html

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

[Relevant CodePen](https://codepen.io/Qumez/pen/OJMZWZL)

`v-for="index in 6"` is going to start at 1:
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6.

But arrays start at 0.

If your array contains 6 items, this will fail because `itemData[6]` does not exist. In fact, if it did not fail, it would still skip the first item in the array, `itemData[0]`.

In your template, change your binding to:

`{{ itemData[index - 1].name }}`

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that you removed the `this.` part when accessing itemData? I think that is what was causing the error in the first place.

Comment: This doesn't seem to fix it - I tried just calling itemData[0] as this works outside the loop, but it stops working when inside the loop.

Comment: Actually, I think your comment may have solved it. You cannot call the itemData with the this prefix when inside the loop as I believe it may think you are referring to an itemData that is local to the loop. Thanks!(Feel free to make a answer that gives the correct answer and I will accept it)

Comment: Hi @willkn - I believe `this`, referring to the Vue Instance, is implicit when doing interpolation. So in the template, you can call your data, props, and computed properties without including `this` between your curly braces. The loop doesn't have any bearing over that - it is the same inside and outside the loop. The only time `itemData` would refer to something other than a computed/prop/data item is if you created your loop as `<div v-for="itemData in itemData">` - and I'm not quite sure that would even work.